# Sudo make install permissions issue on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: opencv, makefile, ubuntu-14.04

I have amended a script from https://github.com/jayrambhia/Install-OpenCV/blob/master/Ubuntu/2.4/opencv2_4_10.sh to try to install OpenCV 2.4.13  onto a vm running Ubuntu 14.04 where I have sudo permission. I'm new to openCV, cmake & make so any help getting this script to work would be appreciated as I have to install it on 20 vm's.

After a few minutes of running the script returns with an error saying can't

`/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /home/myaccount/setups/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.13/build`

and

```
make[2]: *** [3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/depend] Error 2
make[1]: *** [3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/all] Error 2
```

The last few lines of the output is included below and the script is before that.

**Any ideas why the script wont complete successfully or how to correct the permissions issue?**

**Extra Details**

I'm not sure if these are relevant but as I dig into the problem I'll update this section

- cmake version 2.8
- Makerfile mentions # The shell in which to execute make rules. SHELL
  = /bin/sh but my terminal reports echo $0 as bash
- when I run `make install V=1` it builds 100% but then reports
  *-- Install configuration: "RELEASE" CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:36 (FILE): file cannot create directory: /usr/local/include/opencv2.  Maybe need administrative privileges*
- But when I run `sudo make install V=1` I get can't cd error above
- Adding Shebang `#!/bin/bash` to the start of my script didn't solve it
- Running the script on a fresh ubuntu local machine alows the script to run but I need to get it running on the hosted vm
- `umask` of setups folder (where script runs and creates a directory is `0022` . Permissions for setups folder is `755`, group = `Domain Users`, Owner = `myaccount` Thats where the source files folder gets created as well as the build folder which is also `755` after it is created

**Script**

```
arch=$(uname -m)
if [ "$arch" == "i686" -o "$arch" == "i386" -o "$arch" == "i486" -o "$arch" == "i586" ]; then
flag=1
else  
flag=0
fi
echo "Installing OpenCV 2.4.13"
mkdir OpenCV
cd OpenCV
echo "Removing any pre-installed ffmpeg and x264"
sudo apt-get -y remove ffmpeg x264 libx264-dev
echo "Installing unzip"
sudo apt-get -y install unzip
echo "Installing Dependenices"
sudo apt-get -y install libopencv-dev
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential checkinstall cmake pkg-config yasm
sudo apt-get -y install libtiff4-dev libjpeg-dev libjasper-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libdc1394-22-dev libxine-dev libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev libv4l-dev
sudo apt-get -y install python-dev python-numpy
sudo apt-get -y install libtbb-dev libeigen3-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libqt4-dev libgtk2.0-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libfaac-dev libmp3lame-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libxvidcore-core-dev
sudo apt-get -y install x264 v4l-utils ffmpeg
sudo apt-get -y install libgtk2.0-dev
echo "Downloading OpenCV 2.4.13"
if ! [ -f "OpenCV-2.4.13.zip" ]; then
  wget -O OpenCV-2.4.13.zip http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.4.13/opencv-2.4.13.zip/download
fi
echo "Installing OpenCV 2.4.13"
if ! [ -d "opencv-2.4.13" ]; then
  unzip OpenCV-2.4.13.zip
fi
rm OpenCV-2.4.13.zip
cd opencv-2.4.13
rm -rf build
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D CUDA_ARCH_BIN=3.2 -D CUDA_ARCH_PTX=3.2 -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D BUILD_TIFF=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON ..
make -j$(nproc)
sudo make install
sudo sh -c 'echo "/usr/local/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf'
sudo ldconfig
echo "OpenCV 2.4.13 ready to be used"
```

**Command Output**

```
[100%] Build Java tests
Buildfile: /home/myaccount/setups/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.13/build/modules/java/test/.build/build.xml

build:

compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/myaccount/setups/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.13/build/modules/java/test/.build/build/classes
    [javac] Compiling 104 source files to /home/myaccount/setups/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.13/build/modules/java/test/.build/build/classes

jar:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/myaccount/setups/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.13/build/modules/java/test/.build/build/jar
      [jar] Building jar: /home/myaccount/setups/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.13/build/modules/java/test/.build/build/jar/opencv-test.jar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 6 seconds
[100%] Built target opencv_test_java
[sudo] password for myaccount: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for myaccount: 
/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /home/myaccount/setups/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.13/build
make[2]: *** [3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/depend] Error 2
make[1]: *** [3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
OpenCV 2.4.13 ready to be used
myaccount@vm-20161023-002:~/setups$
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the right password? `[sudo] password for myaccount: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for myaccount: `

Comment: While I might have entered it incorrectly the 1st time. the 2nd time was correct. Also when I run `sudo make install V=1` directly in the terminal I get the same errors as when `make install` runs via the script

Comment: If I create a local vm of Ubuntu desktop the script runs and installs so how do I identify why the hosted Ubuntu doesn't allow me? Could it have anything to do with the domain account vs a local account

Comment: What's your `umask`?  What are the permissions of the `build` directory and its parent directories?

Comment: umask of setups folder (where script runs and creates a directory is `0022` . Permissions for setups folder is 755, group = Domain Users, Owner = myaccount

Comment: Guess: your home directory is on NFS.  Personally I'd avoid using `sudo` to root to install such software.  Either install it into your home directory, or create a user `local`, issue `chown -R local:local /usr/local` and `sudo -u local` to install software there.

Comment: @reinierpost care to add that as an answer for some credit. Your guess about running on NFS is correct  but if you are open to it I'd like to expand out on your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What popped up into my head to explain the lack of permission problem: if your `/home` is on NFS, `root` may have `nobody`'s permission on files there.  There are quite a few [related questions on StackExchange](https://www.google.nl/search?hl=en&q=root%20nfs%20nobody%20site:stackexchange.com).

My solution would be not to try installing third-party software as `root` in the first place.  Executing as `root`, your `make install` can do *anything*, including adding or overwriting files that are already managed by your software package manager.  This may confuse the package manager or even render your system unusable. It's better to install the software somewhere else; `/usr/local` and `/opt` were created for this purpose.  In order to make sure your installation procedure doesn't deviate from this, you can create a different user (which I call `local`), `chown -R` these directories to that user, and install using `sudo -u local` instead of sudoing to `root`.  This will be fine for most installations, and should you run into one that tries to do something requiring `root` permissions (such as writing files to `/etc` or `/usr/bin`, restarting system services, doing tricky things with permissions, etc.), it will fail with an error message, allowing you to decide whether you want this before it has already happened.  I have no idea whether OpenCV requires any such steps.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and helping with my issue